# What does 苦学 and 何浪 mean in this sentence?

Tags: words

In this sentence: 苦学し、何浪もして東大に合格, I can't find the meaning? WhenI search up 浪 via Japanese dictionary, it says 'waves' and 苦学 is 'paying one's own school expenses by working​'.

Comment: Provide the whole sentence please.

Comment: @jack It actually makes sense the way it is.  Not that it ever hurts to add more context, of course…

Comment: @JACK It is the whole sentence....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

苦学する has a second [meaning](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E8%8B%A6%E5%AD%A6):  "to study under adversity"

何浪も means being/doing many times  浪人(it is constructed with the same structure that 何回も("many times").

[浪人](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%B5%AA%E4%BA%BA) means "waiting for another chance to enter university after having failed the yearly entrance examination​" (it can refer to the action or to the person doing this action)

So「苦学し、何浪もして東大に合格」means "Succeed to enter Toudai by studying under adversity and being rounin many times."